# Node JS Server Requests using buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm currently working on creating a menu for my Node JS application and I haven't figured out how to make server requests without using the browsers navigation bar.

My directory structure is as follows.

```
/application/nodeserver.js

            /screens/index.js
            /screens/other.js
            /screens/notfound.js
```

My nodeserver.js is as follows

```
// main

var gv_http = null;
var gv_filestream = null;
var gv_server = null;

// screens

var gv_index = null;
var gv_other = null;
var gv_notfound = null;

// set variables

gv_http = require('http');
gv_filestream = require('fs');
gv_server = gv_http.createServer();

gv_index = require('./screens/index');
gv_other = require('./screens/other');
gv_notfound = require('./screens/notfound');

// server

gv_server.on('request', function(request, response) {

   switch(request.url) {

      case '/':
      case '/index':
         gv_index.gui(response);
         break;

      case '/other':
         gv_other.gui(response);
         break;

      default:
         gv_notfound.gui(response);
         break;

   }

});

gv_server.listen(90);
```

This bit all works fine but the only way I can trigger my case statement is by typing into the browser which brings up my javascript screens.

One of the screens index.js

```
var gv_mainmenu = null;

gv_mainmenu = require('./elements/mainmenu');

var gui = function(response) {

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});

   response.write(
      '<html>' +
      '<body>'
   );

   response.write(
      '<button id="butt_index">' +
      '   index' +
      '</button>' +
      '<button id="butt_other">' +
      '   other' +
      '</button>'
   );

   response.write(
      '<h4>index</h4>'
   );

   response.write(
      '</body>' +
      '</html>'
   );

   response.end();

}

function sendrequest() {

   console.log("request sent");

}

module.exports.gui = gui;
```

Is it possible to simulate this using one of the html buttons? I've only seen this happen with frameworks like Express but I don't want to use one of these while still learning.

*PS*

I know my code may look weird to JavaScript experts but I follow the coding standards of the people I work with and we code primarily with Genero so I try to keep it familiar to them and myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is to add an anchor tab to your buttons so they link to your new page.

```
'<a href="/index"><button id="butt_index">' +
  '   index' +
  '</button></a>'
```